# How to tell VIM to store the viminfo file somewhere else?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to tell vim to save its `viminfo` file somewhere else,
such as in the `.vim` folder?

Answer (score 27):

Try adding `set viminfo+=n~/.vim/viminfo` to your `~/.vimrc` file. From `:help 'viminfo'`:

```
    n       Name of the viminfo file.  The name must immediately follow
            the 'n'.  Must be the last one!  If the "-i" argument was
            given when starting Vim, that file name overrides the one
            given here with 'viminfo'.  Environment variables are expanded
            when opening the file, not when setting the option.
```

Comment: Which doesn't work? The option or the specific value I suggested? Feel free to give it any reasonable path that makes sense for your platform.

Comment: it doesnt work as in, after I added that into my vimrc file, viminfo still gets saved directory under my home folder... Unless I set it manually everytime I open vim, that would work, but not if I have it in vimrc

Comment: @BeyondSora, @sarnold Reread help that is quoted here: «the name must *immediately* follow the 'n'». Purge semicolon out of the answer.

Comment: @ZyX, many thanks! I had just tested with a directory without write access, and was happy to get _an_ error when it didn't work. Sigh. Lesson learned. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
set viminfo='1000,nc:\\users\\abcdef\\_viminfo
```

This works for me in Windows 7.

Comment: Yes, I tried `set viminfo+='1000,n~/.vim/viminfo` instead and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10 with Vim 8.0.x. It even works with a variable, e.g.: `set viminfo='1000,n$VIM/viminfo`.

Comment: What does the 1000 do?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem but had no write permission to my home folder (thus could not create the `~/.vimrc`).

I solved it by modifying (through the Administrator) the _vimrc in `C:\Program Files\VIM` to include the line:

```
let $HOME = $USERPROFILE
```

I placed it at the beginning of the file and it worked well. Just in case someone comes across this question and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286925/881272) didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I know its quite a while now, but I am just mentioning this for future readers.

I was facing the same issue while trying to change the location for viminfo file in vimrc. At last setting the value of `viminfofile` option worked for me.

Added the following to my vimrc:

```
set viminfofile=D:\vim\viminfo
```

*It works for me on windows with vim 8.2*

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

This seems to be a bug in `vim` where `set nocompatible` is not [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) and doesn't follow the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

As a workaround, either:

1. Ensure that you `set nocompatible` (or the equivalent `set nocp`) only *once*, and *at the top* of your `vimrc`.
2. Don't set it again if it's already set:

   ```
   if &compatible | set nocompatible | endif " Avoid side effects if `nocp` already set
   ```

**Explanation and bug illustration**

From [`:help compatible`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27compatible%27) (empahsis mine):

> This is a special kind of option, because when it's set or reset,
>   other options are also changed as a side effect.  **CAREFUL: Setting or
>   resetting this option can have a lot of unexpected effects**: Mappings
>   are interpreted in another way, undo behaves differently, etc.  If you
>   set this option in your vimrc file, you should probably put it at the
>   very start.

Note that `&viminfo` is **not** listed in the side-effects, however the following lines clearly show the side effect upon `&viminfo`:

```
set nocompatible
set viminfo+=nWatch-my-viminfo-file-location-be-ignored
echom &viminfo
set nocompatible " do side effects even though nocomptible is already set
echom 'After 2nd "set nocompatible":'
echom &viminfo
```

Output:

> ```
> '100,<50,s10,h,nWatch-my-viminfo-file-location-be-ignored
> After 2nd "set nocompatible":
> '100,<50,s10,h
> ```

`vim --version | head -1`

> `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 05 2016 16:48:20)`

---

**Resolution**

I have raised two GitHub issues regarding this:

- [Undocumented "set nocompatible" side effect upon &viminfo](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1132)
- [`set nocompatible` not idempotent - setting produces side effects when already set](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1131)

See also Vi StackExchange's question: [Can't move `viminfo` file - &viminfo reverts upon loading vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9717/cant-move-viminfo-file-viminfo-reverts-upon-loading-vim/9744#9744) which I raised before seeing this one.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of settings in the .vimrc affects the use of :set viminfo. The setting of viminfo should be after the setting of nocompatible. After reordering my .vimrc, the above solution to have the viminfo file be located in the .vim directory worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In gvim8.2 on Windows10, following option works to change path of viminfo :

```
set viminfofile=$VIM/.viminfo
```

Write this in .vimrc .

It could to change viminfo file path to under the $VIM.